# Phrasal verbs sources

Tags: discussion

Can a resource-oriented question be appeared at `ELL`? I.e. I'm looking for some language idiom entirely description. Can I ask corresponding question at `ELL`?

Comment: Can you give your question here? We can migrate it to ELL main if it's appropriate, or another Stack if it's more suited there :)

Comment: I'm not sure what a "language idiom entirely description" is. Do you mean a place where you can learn the meanings of idioms? If so, then I don't think that's on-topic on ELL, but I will point you to [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/raining%20cats%20and%20dogs.html).

Comment: Counterpoint: if you mean you have a description of a situation or idea and want to learn an appropriate English idiom for it, that would be on topic.